# Azure Functions doenst use all of assigned instances

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have set the number of instances in app Service Plan to 10 and also disabled autoscaling. Then I have this expectation, that my Azure Function uses all 10 instances.

but my Functions uses only 5 instances (Servers). I would like to ask you, why my function uses only 5 instances although I have assigned 10 instances? Do you have any Idea?

Comment: Maybe you don't have enough load to spread over all 10 instances? What does the usage look like?

Comment: My Azure Function is binded to a BlobStorage. It is triggered if a new file is moved to the blob container and makes some logical operation on it and convert it to a csv format. in the blob contaier I have more then 500.000 files. My expectation was, if I choose 10 instances then I can process 10X faster the files in blob container. But as I said, if I choose 10 instances only 4 or 5 of them are busy

Comment: The fact that you have all those files doesn't necessarily mean they all trigger the function to run... Those are only triggered for _new_ files. Again, could you show us some usage?

Comment: Do you want to see my code?

Comment: @Kaja yes please.

Comment: are you going to show some code?